# IndexOf char within an ReadOnlySpan<byte> of UTF8 bytes

Tags: c#

I'm looking for an efficient, allocation-free (!) implementation of

```
public static int IndexOf(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> utf8Bytes, char @char)
{
   // Should return the index of the first byte of @char within utf8Bytes
   // (not the character index of @char within the string)
}
```

I've not found a way to iterate through the span char by char yet. Utf8Parser does not have an overload supporting single characters.
And System.Text.Encoding seems to work mostly on the entire span, and does allocate internally while doing so.

Is there any builtin functionality I haven't spotted yet? If not, can anyone think of a *reasonable* custom implementation?

Comment: `char` is 16 bit though, so not sure how you could easily search a span of `byte`.

Comment: I'm looking for the index of the first byte beginning @char within utf8Bytes.
And yes, I do think that will come down to parsing char by char - I'm kind of hoping there's some form of utility for doing so though that I haven't spotted yet (but maybe there isn't?)

Comment: You do realise that UTF-8 is a multi-byte representation and depending on culture a character may be 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes (octets)?

Comment: @ChrisBD Well, yes - hence this question ;-) If it wasn't, this would be trivial

Comment: Depending on what exactly it is you're trying to use this for, you may also want to look at pipes and `SequenceReader.TryAdvanceTo`, as the current setup can only work if `utf8Bytes` starts and ends on character boundaries.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to convert `@char` to a utf8 byte span, and search for that?  For example https://dotnetfiddle.net/nc0gcW.  The utf8 byte span can be stackalloc'ed so there's no allocation necessary there.

Comment: @dbc Hmm, I fiddled around with this earlier; at first, I thought that encoding internally allocates as part of this call chain, but it actually looks like Utf8Encoding overrides that with something non-allocating .. I think. I need to dig through a bit more to double check that - if it doesn't allocate, that would absolutely do the trick!

Comment: @Bogey - one way or another you are going to need to convert the `char` to a utf8 byte sequence that may be of variable length.  characters with invalid Unicode values also need to be handled somehow (e.g. isolated low surrogates).   But I suppose you could inline something, see [UTF 8 encoding Algorithm vs UTF 16 Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23502153).

Comment: Note that if your `char @char` is the first part of a surrogate pair, then my approach won't work because the encoder will throw an exception.  Is there any possibility of that, or are you sure that `char` is not part of a surrogate pair?

Comment: Yes, that is a fair assumption to make. In practice, @char is going to be a 1-byte ASCII character (the characters in utf8Bytes however may not be) in my current use case, though I'd ideally want to keep the solution more generic. Not handling surrogate pairs is absolutely fine though

Comment: @Bogey - if you do need to handle surrogates you can use `System.Text.Rune`.  Anyway, should I make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to iterate through the `utf8Bytes` character by character, it may be easier to convert the character to a short stackalloc'ed utf8 byte sequence, and search for that:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    const int MaxBytes = 4;

    public static int IndexOf(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> utf8Bytes, char @char)
    {
        Rune rune;
        try
        {
            rune = new Rune(@char);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            // Malformed unicode character, return -1 or throw?
            return -1;
        }
        return utf8Bytes.IndexOf(rune);
    }       
    
    public static int IndexOf(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> utf8Bytes, Rune @char)
    {
        Span<byte> charBytes = stackalloc byte[MaxBytes];
        var n = @char.EncodeToUtf8(charBytes);
        charBytes = charBytes.Slice(0, n);
        
        for (int i = 0, thisLength = 1; i <= utf8Bytes.Length - charBytes.Length; i += thisLength)
        {
            thisLength = Utf8ByteSequenceLength(utf8Bytes[i]);
            if (thisLength == charBytes.Length && charBytes.CommonPrefixLength(utf8Bytes.Slice(i)) == charBytes.Length)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }       
    
    static int Utf8ByteSequenceLength(byte firstByte)
    {
        //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding
        if (     (firstByte & 0b11111000) == 0b11110000) // 11110xxx
            return 4;
        else if ((firstByte & 0b11110000) == 0b11100000) // 1110xxxx
            return 3;
        else if ((firstByte & 0b11100000) == 0b11000000) // 110xxxxx
            return 2;
        return 1; // Either a 1-byte sequence (matching 0xxxxxxx) or an invalid start byte.
    }
}
```

Notes:

- [`Rune`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune) is a struct introduced in .NET Core 3.x that represents a Unicode scalar value.  If you need to search your `utf8Bytes` for a Unicode codepoint that is not in the [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), you will need to use Rune.

  `Rune` has the added advantage that its method [`Rune.TryEncodeToUtf8()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/Rune.cs#L1056) is lightweight and allocation-free.
- If `char @char` is an invalid Unicode character, the .NET encoding algorithms will throw an exception if you attempt to construct a `Rune` from it.  The above code catches the exception and returns `-1`.  You may wish to rethrow the exception.
- As an alternative, [`Rune.DecodeFromUtf8(ReadOnlySpan<Byte>, Rune, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune.decodefromutf8?view=net-7.0#system-text-rune-decodefromutf8(system-readonlyspan((system-byte))-system-text-rune@-system-int32@)) can be used to iterate through a utf8 byte span Rune by Rune.  You could use that to locate an incoming Rune by index.  However, I suspect doing so would be less efficient than the method above.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ynnyRq).

Answer (score 1):

From .NET 5 onwards, there's a library method [`EncodingExtensions.GetChars`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodingextensions.getchars?view=net-5.0) to help you.

Specifically, you want the overload that gets the byte data from a `ReadOnlySpan` and writes to an `IBufferWriter<char>`, which you can then implement to receive your characters one by one and run whatever on them (your matching algorithm, for example). This solution is allocation-free of course, as long as you put your custom buffer writer in a static field and allocate it only once.

Answer (score 1):

You can negate allocations with `stackalloc`. First approximation can look like:

```cs
static (int Found, int Processed) IndexOf(ReadOnlySpan<byte> utf8Bytes, char @char)
{
    Span<char> chars = stackalloc char[utf8Bytes.Length]; // "worst" case every byte is a separate char
    var proc = Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(utf8Bytes, chars);
    var indexOf = chars.IndexOf(@char);
    if (indexOf > 0)
    {
        Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[indexOf * 4];
        var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chars.Slice(0, indexOf), bytes);
        return (result, proc);
    }
    return (indexOf, proc);
}
```

There are few notes here:

1. Big incoming spans can result in SO
2. Decoding the whole array is not optimal
3. Span can contain "partial" codepoints at start and end so `Processed` should be processed accordingly
4. First two points can be mitigated by processing the incoming span in slices of smaller size (for example reading 4 bytes into 4 chars spand).

Actually I believe that `System.IO.Pipelines` handles the same issues (via [`System.Buffers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/buffers) I believe) though it 1) it can be not completely allocation free I believe 2) I still have not investigated it that much so would not be able to provide a completely working example.